# Add-in adds button to Home without code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have downloaded a [simple XLAM add-in](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=removestyles) (I think it's from Microsoft) to remove all non native styles from the active workbook.
This add-in adds a *Remove Styles* button next to Home/Styles.
However, I looked at the code in the add-in and I can't find any trace of code to add/remove this button.
Can someone explain how to do this magic trick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CustomUI elements are xml code that lives in the workbook. There are couple of ways you can see this.

1. Download the [Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2006/05/26/customuieditor.aspx)
2. Download the Ribbon editor from [YourSumBuddy](http://yoursumbuddy.com/customui-ribbon-xml-editor/)
3. Change the name of the file to RemoveSytles.zip (all Excel docs are really just compressed file). Open the zip file and navigate to the customUI folder. Open customUI.xml in your favorite text editor.

Comment: Thanks Dick, looks exactly the point. I am out of work now (Europe) but I'll check that tomorrow first thing.

Comment: Oops. Fixed the bad link.